# PDF file (COMMERCIAL_INVOICE) generated using com.fedex.ship.stub.CompletedShipmentDetail is not prinitng

Tags: java, pdf, printing, itext, fedex

I am using the Fedex API com.fedex.ship.stub.CompletedShipmentDetail to generate a COMMERCIAL_INVOICE pdf for international shipment, but the generated PDF file fails to print. There are some other pdf files also generated along with this file but they are printing fine. I checked the metadata of both pdf files and observed some differences.

**One which is not printing:**

*PDF Producer: iText 2.1.2 (by lowagie.com)*

*PDF Version 1.5*

**One which is printing:**

*PDF producer: FedEx Services*

*PDF Version: 1.4*

I verified that there is no bug in the code. The same code is able to print some pdf files and not printing the other pdf file. Files are present in the path.

The print is done using the following command from a Linux machine to a Printer:

```
lp -d <PRINTER_NAME> -n 2 <FILE_PATH>
```

Comment: ouch they're stuck on an archaic version of iText. Latest is 7.1.7

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But this was working fine a year back or so.